# gox - throws error for sqlite3 and all the builds are failed

Tags: build, sqlite, go

I have Go application [pravasan](http://github.com/pravasan/pravasan) and in my deploy branch I am trying to execute [`gox`](https://github.com/mitchellh/gox) to build its binaries, I am getting couple of errors and they are

```
18 errors occurred:
--> linux/amd64 error: exit status 2
Stderr: # github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
../../mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3.c:92 unknown #: if
../../mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3.c:94 6c: No such file or directory: mingw.h

--> darwin/386 error: exit status 2
Stderr: # github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
../../mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3.c:92 unknown #: if
../../mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3.c:94 8c: No such file or directory: mingw.h

--> linux/386 error: exit status 2
Stderr: # github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3
../../mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3.c:92 unknown #: if
../../mattn/go-sqlite3/sqlite3.c:94 8c: No such file or directory: mingw.h
```

Do anybody has suggestions to resolve this..

Answer (score 0):

The [gox issue 23](https://github.com/mitchellh/gox/issues/23) mentions:

> if you add `CGO_ENABLED=1` to the environment, it successfully compiles, but does not link (it needs a linux linker still), but gets much further along.
>
> > so maybe we need to add a new `-cgo` flag (or, just do it) to gox to set that.
>
> That seems to be necessary, with [Go 1.4 now being more strict when compiling C source files](http://golang.org/doc/go1.4#gocmd):
>
> Unless `cgo` is being used to build the package, the go command now refuses to compile C source files, since the relevant C compilers (6c etc.) are intended to be removed from the installation in some future release.
> (They are used today only to build part of the runtime.)
> It is difficult to use them correctly in any case, so any extant uses are likely incorrect, so we have disabled them.

Comment: I tried with `GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm CGO_ENABLED=1 go build -o pravasan pravasan.go` but got an error `# runtime/cgo
clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-mno-thumb'`.